# how i get a value from a return statement of sqlserver stored procedure to java?

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, return-value

i'am trying to get into a variable called valorReturn the return statement in my stored procedure of sql server...
The sqlserver stored procedure is working fine, but the problem is java..

```
create procedure login
@cliente varchar(10),@pw varchar(10)
as begin
if exists(select cliente from seg where cliente=@cliente)
begin
if(select pw from seg where cliente=@cliente)=@pw
begin
   if(select privilegio from seg where cliente=@cliente)=0 begin
print 0
return 0
end
end

exec 'xd','xd'
```

> here i get a message from PRINT line:
>   0

so, i should be able get the value and set it into variable valorReturn with this JAVA code

```
String consulta="exec login '"+usr+"','"+pw+"'";
CallableStatement st=con.prepareCall(consulta);
st.setInt(1,10);
st.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
st.execute();
int valorReturn=st.getInt(1);
```

this is the exception printed in console

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: index 1 is out of bound.

thanks, i appreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL needs to provide an output parameter to bind onto.

### SQL:

```
create procedure login
    @cliente varchar(10), @pw varchar(10), @result INT = -1 OUTPUT
    as begin
    if exists(select cliente from seg where cliente=@cliente)
    begin
    if(select pw from seg where cliente=@cliente)=@pw
        begin
        if(select privilegio from seg where cliente=@cliente)=0 begin
        print 0
        SET @result = 0 -- new parameter
       return 0
    end
end
```

### Java:

```
    String consulta="exec login ?,?,?"; //moved out to parameters to avoid SQL injection.
    CallableStatement st= con.prepareCall(consulta);
    st.setString(1,usr);
    st.setString(2,pw);
    st.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
    st.execute();
    int valorReturn=st.getInt(3);
```

More information can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-a-stored-procedure-with-output-parameters